# Username state gets undefined / null after a few minutes in JWT authentication React Django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am making a React application with the backend of the Django REST framework. Everything works fine except when retrieving the username. Retrieving the username is no problem but keeping it for a time is a problem. I'm going to explain using comments now in the code;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Nav from './Components/Navbar';
import LoginForm from './Components/LoginForm';
import SignupForm from './Components/SignupForm';

import Layout from './Containers/Layout';

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayed_form: '',
      logged_in: localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false,
      username: '', // username state
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.logged_in) {
      fetch('http://localhost:8000/core/current_user/', { // fetch is used to get current user
        headers: {
          Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          this.setState({ username: json.username }); // set the state 
        });
    }
  }

  handle_login = (e, data) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/token-auth/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        try {
        localStorage.setItem('token', json.token);
        this.setState({
          logged_in: true,
          displayed_form: '',
          username: json.user.username,
          error: '',
        })
      } catch (error) {
       this.setState({error: "We Couldn't log you in, maybe theres a typo in the data you entered"})
       this.handle_logout()
      }
      });
  };

  handle_signup = (e, data) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/core/users/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        try {
          localStorage.setItem('token', json.token);
          this.setState({
            logged_in: true,
            displayed_form: '',
            username: json.username,
          })
          if (this.state.username == 'A user with that username already exists.') {
            this.setState({logged_in: false, username: '', error: 'Yikes, we could not create your account, you have used an existing username. Try again please...'})
            this.handle_logout()
          }
        } catch (error) {
          alert("Error")
        }
      });
  };

  handle_logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.setState({ logged_in: false, username: '' });
  };

  display_form = form => {
    this.setState({
      displayed_form: form
    });
  };

  render() {
    let form;
    switch (this.state.displayed_form) {
      case 'login':
        form = <LoginForm handle_login={this.handle_login} />;
        break;
      case 'signup':
        form = <SignupForm handle_signup={this.handle_signup} />;
        break;
      default:
        { 
          this.state.logged_in ?

          form = null

          :
          
          form = <LoginForm handle_login={this.handle_login} />
        }
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Nav
          logged_in={this.state.logged_in}
          display_form={this.display_form}
          handle_logout={this.handle_logout}
        />
        {form}
        <h3>
          {
            this.state.logged_in && this.state.username !== undefined ? 
            
            <Layout username={this.state.username} />
            
            :  this.state.error ?

            <p className="error">{this.state.error}</p>

            : this.state.username == undefined ?

            <div>
              <p className="error" style={{maxWidth: 650, minHeight: 30, padding: 20}}>You exceeded the time being logged in, we take your account safety seriously. So please logout now and login again...</p>
              {this.handle_logout}
            </div>

            :

            <p></p>
            
          }
        </h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

If you read through everything, I have said that `this.state.logged_in && this.state.username !== undefined ?` show the layout component.

In that component, I have put an h1 with `{this.state.username}`.

The username gets shown but it becomes null/undefined after about 5 minutes. Even though, in the backend Django REST API, the current username can be seen.

I am very confused about why this is happening.

***Update***

I fixed this by using local storage to set a username and get the username. But, I want to know if this is safe.

Comment: Are there any API calls that are made after 5 minutes ?

Comment: No there aren't any